# Get ngModel value from $scope without it's exact name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What I need is to get value of my model from my directive

```
<input type="number" 
       placeholder="must be numeric" 
       class="form-control" 
       name="meter_count" 
       ng-model="sllr.entity.MeterCount" 
       is-number>
```

But I would like to get it dynamically, not like this: `var mdl = scope.sllr.entity.MeterCount` but this:`var mdl = scope.myNgModel`

Comment: You can do something ugly like `angular.element("#theIdOfTheInput").controller("ngModel").$modelValue`, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I would like to create a numeric validation directive accross the app. In your case I still need to know #theIdOfTheInput. Can you suggest some more practical solution?

Comment: You mean in the directive `is-number`? You can just bind your `ngModel` to the `scope` of your directive, or even better require the `ngModel`

Comment: Your `directive` should not care about the original ng-model object name at all. Bind it to a new `$scope` param inside your directive header. Like: `scope: { ngModel: "=" }`.

Comment: Yes your both similar suggestions were wiser than I did. I found a different way to solve my problem. But since I achieved to pass the value of scope variable with your suggestion, please add the answer so I can mark it. Since @devcon answer was earlier, I will accept his answer if he writes.